# grabbing image from folder based on size

Tags: php, image, directory

ok so i have a folder that was created after this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908679/unzip-specific-extension-only/908716#908716) was used

so now i have a folder with with many folders in it
each one having images and a .txt file

the images are almost all .jpg

so now i want to display a image from each folder, using php
i want to display the first image from each folder, and if there is no images i want to display a default image

so by just have the location of the folder i want to display the image

any ideas?
it can be through php or javascript, no other languages please
it will untimely be used in a wordpress theme with the folder location being a custom field parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [PHP glob](http://www.php.net/glob) - it returns an array of filenames in any folder you give it. You can filter by *.jpg, and just use the first item in the array.

For example, I use:

```
$imageArray = glob($folder . "/image*.jpg");
```

which makes an array of all filenames called image[something].jpg in the folder `$folder`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$record_ratio = 0;
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $info = getimagesize($filename);
    $ratio = $info[0] / $info[1];
    if (abs(1 - $ratio) < abs(1 - $record_ratio)) {
      $record_ratio = $ratio;
      $record_filename = $filename;
    }
    if (record_ratio == 1) break;
}
if ($record_ratio > 0) {
  echo '<img src="'.$record_filename.'" height=150px><br>';
}

?>

<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
        echo nl2br(file_get_contents($filename));
        echo "<br></br>";
}
?>
```